# Karate #regex; unable to validate partial matches

Tags: automated-tests, karate

I'm playing with Karate's `#regex` validation and running into an issue.

When I have a file like this `pravda-text_field-OIQSNP`, I am only looking to match the *first* part of the string and hyphen, in this case `pravda-`

Here is what my attempt looks like:

```
And match each $.items contains { filename: \\Apravda- } 
// I'm using double back-slashes for the escape char
```

When I run the test the assertion fails only saying "reason: regex match failed"

What am I doing wrong with my validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work,

```
And match data.items contains {filename : "#regex pravda-.+" }
```

`#regex` in karate supports only full match I believe,

so if you are writing a regex for matching make sure your entire string matches for the expression or at least escape the remaining string as it did above using `.+`